# Updating Tableview Cells with a Button in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello everybody i was wonder if you can update the cells inside of a button? Ive have the code where the button is pressed and it gets your lat/lng and print them out, but now i'm trying to update the Lat and Lng cells in my other swift file *CoordinatesAltitudeDegreesTableViewCell.swift*
as of now my tableview functions seem to work and i tested updating the cell in the function in the viewController and it works.

**My question is anyway to put those functions in the button so the lat/lng variables are in scope**

**Sidenote: ive been looking for solutions for two days and i could seem to find any page that helped me, hopefully this isnt a repost and if there is then sorry in advance**

*again, sorry i am very new to swift programming

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class myTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

//----------------------
// Buttons and Variables
//----------------------
var lastLocation: CLLocation? = nil
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBAction func generateInfo(sender: AnyObject) {

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    let lat: Double! = lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude
    let lng: Double! = lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude
    let alt: Double! = lastLocation?.altitude
    print(lat)
    print(lng)
    print(alt)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

} // end of button

//--------------
// Main Function
//--------------
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("Hello World")

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//-------------------
// LOCATION FUNCTIONS
//-------------------
// Represents Location Manager
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    return manager
}()
// Location Authorization Function
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
    if case .authorizedWhenInUse = status {
        manager.requestLocation()
    } else {
        print("yeah... that didn't work")
    }
}
// Location Error handle
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("that didn't work")
}

// Location Object
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

    if let location = locations.first {
        lastLocation = location
    }
}

//--------------------
// TABLEVIEW FUNCTIONS
//--------------------
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 10
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCellCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCellTableViewCell


        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1{
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "coordinatesAltitudeDegreesCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CoordinatesAltitudeDegreesTableViewCell
        cell.latLabel.text = "text"
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "censusGeographyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CensusGeographyTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nearestAddressCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! NearestAddressTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 4{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "populationCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! PopulationTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 5{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ethnicityCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! EthnicityTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 6{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "raceCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! RaceTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 7{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ageCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! AgeTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 8{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "populationPyramidCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! PopulationPyramidTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "houseHoldCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! HouseHoldTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 300
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1{
        return 130
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2{
        return 100
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3{
        return 100
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 4{
        return 90
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 5{
        return 110
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 6{
        return 200
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 7{
        return 300
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 8{
        return 300
    }
    else {
        return 360
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have variables inside your class for `lat, long, alt` and in your `CoordinatesAltitudeDegreesTableViewCell` you also should have those variables.

So for example here's a code snippet.

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    // Set these attributes here cause they will be used as your source of data for the UITableViewCell
    var lat: Int = 0  
    var lon: Int = 0
    var alt: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var someButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.someButtonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    func someButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        lat = 100 // set to different values
        lon = 10 // set to different values
        alt = 30 // set to different values

        // when you reload the tableView all the `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` codes will be called again therefore refreshing your cells.
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension SomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SomeCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! SomeCustomCell

        // set the parameters
        cell.lat = self.lat 
        cell.lon = self.lon
        cell.alt = self.atl

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

class SomeCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var lat: Int = 0 {
        didSet { // just in case you don't know about didSet there's an explanation below
            lblLat.text = "\(lat)"
        }
    }
    var lon: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            lblLon.text = "\(lon)"
        }
    }
    var alt: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            lblAlt.text = "\(alt)"
        }
    }

    ... insert some ui objects here 
    @IBOutlet var lblLat: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblLon: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblAlt: UILabel!
    ... insert some ui objects here

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

There are a multitude of ways to do this, but this is the simplest one I can think of.

**didSet explanation**

```
var someVariable: <SomeDataType> = <SomeValue> {
    didSet {
        // this block is called whenever this variable's value is changed (i.e someVariable)
    }
}
```

for example:

```
var name: String = "" {
    didSet {
        print(name)
    }
}

init() {
    name = "Capaldi"
    name = "Tennant"
    name = "Smith"
    name = "Eccleston"
}
```

In your debugger it would output something like this since didSet was called each time you set the name

```
Capaldi
Tennant
Smith
Eccleston
```

Comment: Hey Zonily, I'm sorry it took so long to comment back but seriously thank you. I'm trying to implement this now but I can actually understand what your code is saying so hopefully this works and ill let you know if does!

Comment: @MaclaneNugent upvoting my answer and marking it as the correct one is all the thanks I need. If you need any more help just comment here and I'll revise my answer.

Comment: the only problem I'm running into in the addTarget part. i have **        generate.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.someButtonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)
** and it says "Value of type 'uiBarButtonItem' has no member 'addTarget' "

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` is not a `UIButton` but you could simply do this instead. `someBarButtonItem.selector = #selector(self.someFunction)`

Comment: hey, i figured it out. seriously thanks, I already marked your answer as correct!